# Async Progress trouble with the Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, progress

I am trying to implement the Async Progress Pattern to my program. But I am stuck at a rather embarassing point: I am unable to assign the event Handler.

My code looks like this:
The event is handeld in an extra window:

```
public ProgressReportViewModel(IWindowManager windManager, Progress<ProgressReport> progressReport)
{
    this.ProgressReport = progressReport;
    this.ProgressReport.ProgressChanged += HandleProgressChanged;
}

    public void HandleProgressChanged(ProgressReport report)
    {
```

// do stuff.
        }

If I am trying to compile, I get the following error:
No overload for 'HandleProgressChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Why does this error occur? Do I have a flaw in my understanding of Event handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Progress<T>.ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137516.aspx) event has a delegate of type [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx), which has this signature:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
    Object sender,
    TEventArgs e
)
```

Change your code to this:

```
public void HandleProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressReport report)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer! I am a little confused why the tutorial from Microsoft does not mention this...

Comment: @ChristianSauer Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: I used this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

The coding syntax is a little bit different, but the ReportProgress Signature has no Sender object and seems to be handling the event.

Comment: In the code in that article they're calling the [`Progress<T>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160061.aspx) which takes an `Action<T>`, but if you use the event after it's constructed, your handler has to have the `Object sender` parameter.

Comment: A thank you very much. I am not really familiar with the Action<T> concept so I did not understand that.